# Should I return an array to Model or return one object of array and update Model Vuejs by JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I working with treeview in Vuejs, this treeview include parent and children.
Every update, I call API to update data to database I can return an array Categories to update to Model Categories OR return Object Category and use JS code to update model Categories. Which case Update, because It have 4 cases: update don't change parent, change parent, parent -> children, children -> parent. So that, code JS to update for Model is harder than return table:

```
// Update by return Array Categories
this.categories = response.data
this.active = []
this.editedCateory = null
this.$refs.form.reset()

//Update by use JS when return Object Category
this.updated = response.data
this.editedCateory.name = updated.name
this.editedCateory.url = updated.url
if(this.editedCateory.parent && !updated.parent)
{
    let oldparent = this.categories.filter(v=>v.id == this.editedCateory.parent)
    oldparent[0].children = oldparent[0].children.filter(v=>v.id != updated.id)
    updated = Object.assign({}, updated, {'children':[]})
    this.categories.push(updated)
}
else if(!this.editedCateory.parent && updated.parent)
{
    this.categories = this.categories.filter(v=>v.id != updated.id)
    let newparent = this.categories.filter(v=>v.id == updated.parent)
    newparent[0].children.push(updated)
}
else if(this.editedCateory.parent && updated.parent && (this.editedCateory.parent != updated.parent))
{
    let oldparent = this.categories.filter(v=>v.id == this.editedCateory.parent)
    oldparent[0].children = oldparent[0].children.filter(v=>v.id != updated.id)
    let newparent = this.categories.filter(v=>v.id == updated.parent)
    newparent[0].children.push(updated)
}
this.active = []
this.editedCateory = null
this.$refs.form.reset()
```

I'm coding Vuejs, I think I ought to use JS update Model but it's more complex.

**That thought is right or wrong?** Thank for viewing

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it makes sense after update just call again API with categories and set Categories again? Vue re-render component if data changed. With VUEX it seems easier.